# Make Tools more visible

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, usability

The link to moderation [Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) is a bit hard to see.

[image]

This, accompanied to the fact that Tools doesn't appear in the links at the top of the page, makes access to Tools a bit harder to find than, say, access to suggested edits and other reviews.

I find myself not entering to the Tools page for weeks, until I remember again that it exists.

A suggest using a different, more visible colour for the link to the Tools page.